# Unable to catch event emitted from child component in Angular 2+

Tags: angular, typescript

This is a newbie question. I am trying to emit a message from the child component to the parent component but unable to get it to work.

app.component.html

`<app-cart-component> [items]="rootItems" (outputItems)="handleChange($event)" </app-cart-component>`

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  rootItems = ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Cherries']
  title = 'inputOutputEventemitter';

  handleChange($event){
    console.log("pushing item to rootItems" + $event)
    this.rootItems.push($event)
    
  }

}
```

cart-component.component.html

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="newItem">
<button (click)='addToList()'> Add to List</button>
```

cart-component.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart-component',
  templateUrl: './cart-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart-component.component.css']
})
export class CartComponentComponent implements OnInit {

  newItem = ''

  @Input() items = []
  @Output() outputItems = new EventEmitter<string>()

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addToList(): void {
    this.items.push(this.newItem)
    
    this.outputItems.emit(this.newItem)

    console.log("from CartComponentComponent emitting" + this.newItem)
  }

}
```

Comment: What's the issue? Are you seeing any errors on the console? Did those console.log messages print something on the console?

Comment: I noticed strange html: <app-cart-component> [items]="rootItems" (outputItems)="handleChange($event)" </app-cart-component>, it should be <app-cart-component [items]="rootItems" (outputItems)="handleChange($event)"></app-cart-component>, maybe it's reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution provided by Valery seems to resolve the issue.

```
<app-cart-component [items]="rootItems" (outputItems)="handleChange($event)"></app-cart-component>
```

The above line from html resolved the problem. Thanks Valery.